# Setup project not registering in registry

Tags: asp.net, registry, installation, web-setup-project

I have a VS Web setup project.

I want to register the physical path of the application.

In the setup project, I created a new key in HKLM, named Software, then I created a new key named "MyCompany", then in the mycompany key, I add the key Installation Folder with value [TARGETDIR].

But when I try my installer, and go to regedit after successful installation, the registry-key is not there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself: 
if Wow64 then
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\
else
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\YourCompany]
"Installation Folder"="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UsersInstallFolder\"

Comment: how to force it to create regedit in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\